# I want to run same code with different data concurrently

Tags: ios

I want to run same code with different data concurrently.
please let me know ,how to do.
scenario- i have moving car in map ,single car working fine .now i want to add another car, so i have to use same code but both car should seem moving concurrently.

Comment: How is the car communicating with your code? Where is your code running? What language? What framework?

Comment: you need to be more specific here